# Browser MS Edge: How to navigate to DOM from console

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge

If using Chrome, if I type `$(selector)` in console, it will output founded node. Clicking on that node in console will open Dev Tools Elements Tab and auto focus on that node thus allowing me to inspect surrounding node, add class, delete etc.

How to do the same on Edge 44.18362.449.0? When I type `$(selector)`, the console display the node just like chrome but I can't click on it to focus on Elements Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can navigate to DOM directly in Dev Tools Elements Tab in MS Edge. You could enter the selector in the search bar on the top of right in Elements Tab, then it will auto focus on the node:

[image]